# How to mark the maximum and minimum positions of the chart path "@rainbow-me/animated-charts" library in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graph, charts, linechart

I'm using this library for charts.How can we mark the peak value and minimum value on the chart Path.
I have attached the code and screenshot for this.

```
       <ChartPathProvider
                    data={{
                      points: monotoneCubicInterpolation({
                        data,
                        range: 40,
                      }),
                      smoothingStrategy: "bezier",
                    }}
                  >
                    <View>
                      <ChartPath
                        height={moderateScale(280)}
                        stroke={COLORS.greenChart}
                        strokeWidth={3}
                        width={screenWidth}
                      />

                    </View>
                  </ChartPathProvider>
```

[image: simple graph]